# Calculate average from uniquely identified pair of columns in dataframe in R

Tags: r, average, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe like this, which covers a month worth of data:

[image: dataframe for month data]

And I need to calculate the average Points per month for a unique combination of the 2 IDs. For example, the first row has ID1 1511960 and ID2 2942487 and has 22 points.  This unique combination of IDs will occur many times through this month of data.  So I need to add the points for this combination of IDs for however many times it occurs throughout the dataframe, and then divide this sum by the number of times this combination occurred; thus getting the average points.

I need to do this for every unique combination of the 2 IDs. So if that first combination I used as an example occurred 14 times in this month, we would have 14 point values summed (the first one was 22) divided by 14.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `aggregate`:

```
#Example data
df <- data.frame(ID1 = round(runif(100,1,10)), ID2 = round(runif(100,1,10)), Points = round(runif(100, 1,50)))

aggregate(Points ~ ID1 + ID2, df, mean)
#   ID1 ID2 Points
# 1   2   1     12
# 2   5   1     31
# 3   7   1     48
# 4  10   1      3
# 5   1   2     20
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution using `data.table` package. Convert your data.frame `df` to data.table `dt`.

```
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, mean(Points), by = list(ID1, ID2)]
```

Comment: The `aggregate` function was built in to base R for this purpose.

Comment: Also, this package is no longer available starting with (R version 3.0.2)

Comment: @RobertKrzyzanowski, true, but the syntax of `data.table` is very nice. And it could be much faster comparing to `aggregate` for large data sets.

Comment: @Cybernetic, The package `data.table` is available.

Comment: My mistake...it is available. Thank you for your answer. I get the following error when I try this approach:  Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , av.points = mean(Points), by = list(ID1,  : 
  unused argument (av.points = mean(Points))

Comment: @Cybernetic, I am sorry, it was my mistake. See the updated answer.